# Ordinal with cofinality $\Omega_\omega$?

Tags: ordinals

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchholz_psi_functions it is written :
"If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal then $cof(\alpha) \in \lbrace \omega \rbrace \cup \lbrace \Omega_{\mu+1} | \mu \ge 0 \rbrace$".

Does it mean that a limit ordinal cannot have a cofinality of $\Omega_\omega$, and why ?

Comment: Just to clarify: by $\Omega_{\omega}$ you mean $\aleph_{\omega}$, as in the article?

Comment: Yes, the definition of $\Omega_\nu$ is : 1 if $\nu = 0$, $\aleph_\nu$ if $\nu > 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the cofinality of $\aleph_{\omega}$ itself is $\omega$, so if there is an unbounded subset $A \subseteq \alpha$ of size $\aleph_{\omega}$, then there is also an unbounded subset of size $\omega$.